# Dynamics 365: Init of Application Insights logging for Javascript in external files

Tags: javascript, logging, azure-application-insights, require, microsoft-dynamics

I want to put my connectionstring and the init of the AppInsights-Logger in separate files and use (import) the logger in my main javascript file.

What I have done so far causes the main file not to load properly and I'm struggling to find the cause.

In my **main.js** I use the require declaration:

```
const appInsights = require('logger);
```

In the **logger.js** I have (also require the config file):

```
const appInsightsConnectionString = require('loggerconfig');

!function (v, y, T) { var S = v.location, k = "script", D = "instrumentationKey", C = "ingestionendpoint", I = "disableExceptionTracking", E = "ai.device.", b = "toLowerCase", w = (D[b](), "crossOrigin"), N = "POST", e = "appInsightsSDK", t = T.name || "appInsights", n = ((T.name || v[e]) && (v[e] = t), v[t] || function (l) { var u = !1, d = !1, g = { initialize: !0, queue: [], sv: "6", version: 2, config: l }; function m(e, t) { var n = {}, a = "Browser"; return n[E + "id"] = a[b](), n[E + "type"] = a, n["ai.operation.name"] = S && S.pathname || "_unknown_", n["ai.internal.sdkVersion"] = "javascript:snippet_" + (g.sv || g.version), { time: (a = new Date).getUTCFullYear() + "-" + i(1 + a.getUTCMonth()) + "-" + i(a.getUTCDate()) + "T" + i(a.getUTCHours()) + ":" + i(a.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + i(a.getUTCSeconds()) + "." + (a.getUTCMilliseconds() / 1e3).toFixed(3).slice(2, 5) + "Z", iKey: e, name: "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights." + e.replace(/-/g, "") + "." + t, sampleRate: 100, tags: n, data: { baseData: { ver: 2 } } }; function i(e) { e = "" + e; return 1 === e.length ? "0" + e : e } } var e, n, f = l.url || T.src; function a(e) { var t, n, a, i, o, s, r, c, p; u = !0, g.queue = [], d || (d = !0, i = f, r = (c = function () { var e, t = {}, n = l.connectionString; if (n) for (var a = n.split(";"), i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { var o = a[i].split("="); 2 === o.length && (t[o[0][b]()] = o[1]) } return t[C] || (t[C] = "https://" + ((e = (n = t.endpointsuffix) ? t.location : null) ? e + "." : "") + "dc." + (n || "services.visualstudio.com")), t }()).instrumentationkey || l[D] || "", c = (c = c[C]) ? c + "/v2/track" : l.endpointUrl, (p = []).push((t = "SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details)", n = i, o = c, (s = (a = m(r, "Exception")).data).baseType = "ExceptionData", s.baseData.exceptions = [{ typeName: "SDKLoadFailed", message: t.replace(/\./g, "-"), hasFullStack: !1, stack: t + "\nSnippet failed to load [" + n + "] -- Telemetry is disabled\nHelp Link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2128109\nHost: " + (S && S.pathname || "_unknown_") + "\nEndpoint: " + o, parsedStack: [] }], a)), p.push((s = i, t = c, (o = (n = m(r, "Message")).data).baseType = "MessageData", (a = o.baseData).message = 'AI (Internal): 99 message:"' + ("SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details) (" + s + ")").replace(/\"/g, "") + '"', a.properties = { endpoint: t }, n)), i = p, r = c, JSON && ((o = v.fetch) && !T.useXhr ? o(r, { method: N, body: JSON.stringify(i), mode: "cors" }) : XMLHttpRequest && ((s = new XMLHttpRequest).open(N, r), s.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"), s.send(JSON.stringify(i))))) } function i(e, t) { d || setTimeout(function () { !t && g.core || a() }, 500) } f && ((n = y.createElement(k)).src = f, !(o = T[w]) && "" !== o || "undefined" == n[w] || (n[w] = o), n.onload = i, n.onerror = a, n.onreadystatechange = function (e, t) { "loaded" !== n.readyState && "complete" !== n.readyState || i(0, t) }, e = n, T.ld < 0 ? y.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e) : setTimeout(function () { y.getElementsByTagName(k)[0].parentNode.appendChild(e) }, T.ld || 0)); try { g.cookie = y.cookie } catch (h) { } function t(e) { for (; e.length;)!function (t) { g[t] = function () { var e = arguments; u || g.queue.push(function () { g[t].apply(g, e) }) } }(e.pop()) } var s, r, o = "track", c = "TrackPage", p = "TrackEvent", o = (t([o + "Event", o + "PageView", o + "Exception", o + "Trace", o + "DependencyData", o + "Metric", o + "PageViewPerformance", "start" + c, "stop" + c, "start" + p, "stop" + p, "addTelemetryInitializer", "setAuthenticatedUserContext", "clearAuthenticatedUserContext", "flush"]), g.SeverityLevel = { Verbose: 0, Information: 1, Warning: 2, Error: 3, Critical: 4 }, (l.extensionConfig || {}).ApplicationInsightsAnalytics || {}); return !0 !== l[I] && !0 !== o[I] && (t(["_" + (s = "onerror")]), r = v[s], v[s] = function (e, t, n, a, i) { var o = r && r(e, t, n, a, i); return !0 !== o && g["_" + s]({ message: e, url: t, lineNumber: n, columnNumber: a, error: i, evt: v.event }), o }, l.autoExceptionInstrumented = !0), g }(T.cfg)); function a() { T.onInit && T.onInit(n) } (v[t] = n).queue && 0 === n.queue.length ? (n.queue.push(a), n.trackPageView({})) : a() }(window, document, {
    src: "https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js",
    name: "appInsights",
    // ld: 0,
    // useXhr: 1,
    crossOrigin: "anonymous",
    // onInit: null,
    cfg: {
        // Application Insights Configuration
        connectionString: appInsightsConnectionString
    }
});


const logger = appInsights
module.exports = logger;
```

In **loggerconfig.js** I have:

```
const connectionString = "InstrumentationKey = 1265464-0000-0000-0000-00000000000; IngestionEndpoint = https://westeurope-5.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westeurope.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/";
module.exports = connectionString;
```

So in general this must work this way right?

**UPDATE 11.08.2023**

When I use the following code, I get the error "require not defined at xxxx":

```
try {
    console.log("importing... ");
    const { logCustomTrace } = require('./logger');
    //import { sendCustomTrace } from './logger';
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

The strange this is the following. When I set a Breakpoint on the first line in the Try-Block, the breakpoint is hit. When I use "import" the same breakpoint is not hit. Why?! I am completely confused about that.

QUESTION:
When I set the dependencies in the Dynamics Webresources correctly, would this be aequivalent to importing theses files/modules?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If you're integrating Application Insights logging for a Dynamics 365 project using external JavaScript files, here's how you can structure the   code  with a sample example :

**loggerconfig.js:**

```java
const connectionString = "InstrumentationKey=d03e30b9-6973-4f6c-8a3c-e9f2cf5a8ec1;IngestionEndpoint=https://westeurope-5.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westeurope.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/";

module.exports = connectionString;
```

**logger.js:**

```java
const { ApplicationInsights } = require('@microsoft/applicationinsights-web');
const connectionString = require('./loggerconfig');

const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
  config: {
    connectionString: connectionString,
  },
});
appInsights.loadAppInsights();
appInsights.trackPageView();

function sendCustomEvent(eventName, properties = {}) {
  appInsights.trackEvent({ name: eventName, properties });
}

module.exports = {
  sendCustomEvent,
};
```

**logger.js:**

```
const { sendCustomEvent } = require('./logger');

// Sending a custom event with properties
sendCustomEvent('CustomEvent', { key1: '2', key2: '3' });

// Log a message to indicate telemetry has been sent
console.log('Sent Telemetry...');
```

`node main.js`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Super, thx for the hint. I'll try it out and give feedback :)

Comment: @PaulRichardson Sure the last file is `main.js`

Comment: @PaulRichardson Place the files with the same folder .

Comment: An additional question. Do I have to add a dependency to the webressources in dynamics? For Example config.js -> logger.js -> main.js? Or does this work without dependency?

Comment: @PaulRichardson AFIK Yes works without dependency but when you're working with JavaScript files and want to ensure proper execution order, it's often a good practice to manage dependencies explicitly. This ensures that the required scripts are loaded in the correct order, avoiding issues that might arise due to dependencies not being available when needed.

Comment: I know now whats the issue. I get the following error when using require:

"require is not defined at xxxxx"

This seems to occur if require is used in a browser context. so I try to refactor it using "import" and see if it helps. If not how can I import JS files in a dynamics 365 environment. I mean this must be possible...

Comment: [JS files](https://dynamics-chronicles.com/article/dynamics-365-typescript-web-resource-tutorial) to a Dynamics 365 [environment](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-upload-external-javascript-file-inside-dynamics-365-nishant-arora#:~:text=To%20fix%20this%2C%20we%20need%20to%20remove%20the,can%20upload%20web%20file%20inside%20the%20portal.%205.).

Comment: Added an update at the bottom of my question.

Comment: could please tell me what does equivalent of importing these files/modules is?

Comment: I mean the following: When I set the dependencies for every relevant webresource in dynamics like "main.js -> logger.js -> loggerconfig.js" would this implicitly make the exported modules/functions available so that I dont need to import them explicitly?

I think the issue with"require is not available at xxx" is a browser issue but when using "import" it seems not to work either...so I'm quite stuck

Comment: At the end my main issue is that the breakpoint is hit when I use "require" allthough it says "require is not defined at xxx". But when I use "import" the exact same breakpoint is not hit. It seems that in this case the main.js is not even loaded. Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: Web resource [dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/web-resource-dependencies?view=op-9-1) Script [JScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/script-jscript-web-resources?view=op-9-1).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254883/discussion-between-sampath-and-paul-richardson).